# How to integrate Quickbook web connector with Web API

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, quickbooks, qbfc

I was told to integrate our application with QuickBook Desktop version. When i checked about that, Connecting via WebConnector seems promising. But all the documents and samples are created with WebService.

But i want to implement the functionalities with WebAPI. Is that possible and that will work without any issues (still in research, so i haven't tried it yet)? i have searched for reference but no help. May be i looked in wrong places.

Secondly, the webservice example uses qbXML to send and receive data with WebConnector. Is there any possibility that i can use Interop library QBFC ?

Any help appreciated thanks.

Note: I have referred the Samples and Docs that comes with SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But all the documents and samples are created with WebService.

You should use the Web Connector, which requires you to implement a SOAP web service.

> But i want to implement the functionalities with WebAPI.

No, QuickBooks desktop does not support a REST API of any sort natively (though if you want to pay, Autofy http://www.propelware.com/ has a solution for you).

> i have searched for reference but no help. May be i looked in wrong places.

You should probably start with Intuit's documentation. There's literally a 100+ page PDF on specifically the top of integrating via the Web Connector, and several hundred more pages on QuickBooks integration in general - install the SDK and look at the included PDF docs:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0200_quickbooks_desktop/0100_essentials/0000_overview

> Is there any possibility that i can use Interop library QBFC ?

QBFC can generate qbXML requests. So you can use that to generate qbXML requests, yes.

You'll still have to implement some web service components though - you can't use QBFC to natively talk to QuickBooks desktop from a web app.